# Remove quotes in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I get a dictionary like following,

```
{'members': '{"mgt.as.wso2.com": 4100,"as.wso2.com": 4300}', 'subdomain': 'mgt'}
```

In the key members value is passed within two single quotes. Is there a way to remove those single quotes. I want the dictionary like following,

```
{'members': {"mgt.as.wso2.com": 4100,"as.wso2.com": 4300}, 'subdomain': 'mgt'}
```

Comment: Those dictionaries are identical, aren't they?

Comment: Do you want to _print_ the dictionary in the format of the second example? Because the dictionaries themselves are the same. Or do you want to be able to parse either dictionary?

Comment: No. First one contains
'members': '{"mgt.as.wso2.com": 4100,"as.wso2.com": 4300}'

What I need is as below without single quotes
members: {"mgt.as.wso2.com": 4100,"as.wso2.com": 4300}

Comment: Do you want that value to itself be a dictionary?

Comment: @AnubianNoob I want to parse the dictionary. In order to do that I need the  dictionary as in the second format.

Comment: **Does this come from json somewhere earlier**???  Then use `d1['members'] = json.loads(d1['members'])`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Evaluate the string value with `literal_eval`, and then assign it back to the key:

```
>>> import ast
>>> d['members'] = ast.literal_eval(d['members'])
>>> d['members']['as.wso2.com']
4300
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import ast
d = {'clustering': 'true',
 'http_proxy_port': '80',
 'https_proxy_port': '443',
 'localmemberhost': '127.0.1.1',
 'localmemberport': '4100',
 'members': '{"mgt.as.wso2.com": 4100,"as.wso2.com": 4300}',
 'portoffset': '1',
 'stratos_instance_data_mgt_host_name': 'mgt.as.wso2.com',
 'stratos_instance_data_worker_host_name': 'as.wso2.com',
 'subdomain': 'mgt'}

print d
for k, v in d.items():
   if v[0] == '{' and v[-1] == '}':
      d[k] = ast.literal_eval(v)

print d
```

Comment: I'd go for `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `eval()`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yup, you are right, I didn't know about it (fixed)

Comment: Both `print(d)` - Python3 - return the same result: `{'clustering': 'true', 'subdomain': 'mgt'}`, with quotation marks, so no improvement.`v[0]` in the iteration dict loop will be the first char of the value, which is e.g. `t` for `true`.