# Looping through a Dictionary / Ideas?

Tags: python, ssh

I am stuck in water. I am just getting started  with python, here is the background and what I am trying to accomplish...

Background:
I have 44 networked switches each supporting telnet and ssh connections. I also have an Ubuntu Apache Server with the configurations of each device (parsed by a tool called "Nipper" http://sectools.org/tool/nipper/). Nipper works well for what we need. I have a basic understanding of what common terms are in programming... (Lists, Tuples, Dictionaries, etc) but I lack the coding experience.

What I an trying to accomplish:
I just started writing a python program with the intention of automatically connecting to each switch via Telnet/SSH and pulling the configurations of each switch. After I get a functional script, I plan on using "Cron" to schedule the task weekly so we have updated Network Documentation.

Where I am stuck / Where I could use help and ideas:
It is my understanding that my code below reads the "/var/www/html/Directory.txt" file into a dictionary "d". I would like to create a sequential loop for each entry in the dictionary so I can telnet into the device "IP" and grab the "running-config" then save the config to the "outfile" "/var/www/html/Test_Output.csv" .

Any ideas / help to get me the code structure to start this loop process for each entry and be able to reference the "IP" and "filename" as a separate variable / entity would be greatly appreciated. For you people with more experience, Does my "Reference File" allow me to use the "IP" and "Filename" values as a variable or do I need to change the format of the file?

My Code so far:

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python3
    import csv

    d = {}
    with open('/var/www/html/Test_Output.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
      with open('/var/www/html/Directory.txt.bak', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in infile:
          rows = ( line.split(",") for line in infile )
          d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
    print(d)
    #print(d['"01"'])


    #dlist = d.items()
    #dlist.sort()
    #print(dlist)
    #for key, filename in dlist:
    #  print(key, filename)
```

My Reference File:     "/var/www/html/Directory.txt"
Notice the order is... Sequential Key, IP Address, full-path-to-filename

```
    "1",172.16.255.183,/var/www/html/Admin/AdminBld-3.html
    "2",172.16.255.201,/var/www/html/Admin/AdminBldg-1.html
    "3",172.16.255.115,/var/www/html/AV/AV-1.html
    "4",172.16.255.198,/var/www/html/MC/MC-198.html
    "5",172.16.255.101,/var/www/html/MC/MC-1.html
    "6",172.16.255.102,/var/www/html/MC/MC-2.html
    "7",172.16.255.103,/var/www/html/MC/MC-3.html
    "8",172.16.255.104,/var/www/html/MC/MC-4.html
    "9",172.16.255.105,/var/www/html/MC/MC-5.html
    "10",172.16.255.106,/var/www/html/MC/MC-6.html
    "11",172.16.255.108,/var/www/html/MC/MC-8.html
    "12",172.16.255.109,/var/www/html/MC/MC-9.html
    "13",172.16.255.2,/var/www/html/MDF/MDF-2.html
    "14",172.16.255.1,/var/www/html/MDF/MDF-4507.html
    "15",172.16.255.160,/var/www/html/RAM/RAM-2960-1.html
    "16",172.16.255.161,/var/www/html/RAM/RAM-2960-2.html
    "17",172.16.255.107,/var/www/html/SAC/SAC-1.html
    "18",172.16.255.111,/var/www/html/TR/TR1/TR1-1.html
    "19",172.16.255.112,/var/www/html/TR/TR1/TR1-2.html
    "20",172.16.255.113,/var/www/html/TR/TR1/TR1-3.html
    "21",172.16.255.114,/var/www/html/TR/TR1/TR1-4.html
    "22",172.16.255.121,/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2-1.html
    "23",172.16.255.122,/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2-2.html
    "24",172.16.255.123,/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2-3.html
    "25",172.16.255.124,/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2-4.html
    "26",172.16.255.126,/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2_5.html
    "27",172.16.255.131,/var/www/html/TR/TR3/TR3-1.html
    "28",172.16.255.132,/var/www/html/TR/TR3/TR3-2.html
    "29",172.16.255.133,/var/www/html/TR/TR3/TR3-3.html
    "30",172.16.255.134,/var/www/html/TR/TR3/TR3-4.html
    "31",172.16.255.141,/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-1.html
    "32",172.16.255.142,/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-2.html
    "33",172.16.255.143,/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-3.html
    "34',172.16.255.144,/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-4.html
    "35",172.16.255.145,/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-5.html
    "36",172.16.255.151,/var/www/html/TR/TR5/TR5-1.html
    "37",172.16.255.152,/var/www/html/TR/TR5/TR5-2.html
    "38",172.16.255.153,/var/www/html/TR/TR5/TR5-3.html
    "39",172.16.255.181,/var/www/html/TR/TRSW/TRSW-1.html
    "40",172.16.255.184,/var/www/html/TR/TRSW/TRSW-3.html
    "41",172.16.255.171,/var/www/html/TR/TRTC/TRTC-1.html
    "42",172.16.255.172,/var/www/html/TR/TRTC/TRTC-2.html
    "43",172.16.255.173,/var/www/html/TR/TRTC/TRTC-3.html
    "44",172.16.255.175,/var/www/html/TR/TRTC/TRTC_5.html
```

Current Script Output:   (Should be the dictionary "d")

```
    {'"4"': ['172.16.255.198', '/var/www/html/MC/MC-198.html\n'], '"38"': ['172.16.255.153', '/var/www/html/TR/TR5/TR5-3.html\n'], '"16"': ['172.16.255.161', '/var/www/html/RAM/RAM-2960-2.html\n'], '"20"': ['172.16.255.113', '/var/www/html/TR/TR1/TR1-3.html\n'], '"40"': ['172.16.255.184', '/var/www/html/TR/TRSW/TRSW-3.html\n'], '"10"': ['172.16.255.106', '/var/www/html/MC/MC-6.html\n'], '"3"': ['172.16.255.115', '/var/www/html/AV/AV-1.html\n'], '"14"': ['172.16.255.1', '/var/www/html/MDF/MDF-4507.html\n'], '"9"': ['172.16.255.105', '/var/www/html/MC/MC-5.html\n'], '"39"': ['172.16.255.181', '/var/www/html/TR/TRSW/TRSW-1.html\n'], '"43"': ['172.16.255.173', '/var/www/html/TR/TRTC/TRTC-3.html\n'], '"41"': ['172.16.255.171', '/var/www/html/TR/TRTC/TRTC-1.html\n'], '"30"': ['172.16.255.134', '/var/www/html/TR/TR3/TR3-4.html\n'], '"7"': ['172.16.255.103', '/var/www/html/MC/MC-3.html\n'], '"32"': ['172.16.255.142', '/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-2.html\n'], '"29"': ['172.16.255.133', '/var/www/html/TR/TR3/TR3-3.html\n'], '"33"': ['172.16.255.143', '/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-3.html\n'], '"37"': ['172.16.255.152', '/var/www/html/TR/TR5/TR5-2.html\n'], '"17"': ['172.16.255.107', '/var/www/html/SAC/SAC-1.html\n'], '"28"': ['172.16.255.132', '/var/www/html/TR/TR3/TR3-2.html\n'], '"27"': ['172.16.255.131', '/var/www/html/TR/TR3/TR3-1.html\n'], '"2"': ['172.16.255.201', '/var/www/html/Admin/AdminBldg-1.html\n'], '"11"': ['172.16.255.108', '/var/www/html/MC/MC-8.html\n'], '"12"': ['172.16.255.109', '/var/www/html/MC/MC-9.html\n'], '"22"': ['172.16.255.121', '/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2-1.html\n'], '"44"': ['172.16.255.175', '/var/www/html/TR/TRTC/TRTC_5.html\n'], '"34\'': ['172.16.255.144', '/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-4.html\n'], '"1"': ['172.16.255.183', '/var/www/html/Admin/AdminBld-3.html\n'], '"15"': ['172.16.255.160', '/var/www/html/RAM/RAM-2960-1.html\n'], '"26"': ['172.16.255.126', '/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2_5.html\n'], '"35"': ['172.16.255.145', '/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-5.html\n'], '"6"': ['172.16.255.102', '/var/www/html/MC/MC-2.html\n'], '"21"': ['172.16.255.114', '/var/www/html/TR/TR1/TR1-4.html\n'], '"25"': ['172.16.255.124', '/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2-4.html\n'], '"24"': ['172.16.255.123', '/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2-3.html\n'], '"23"': ['172.16.255.122', '/var/www/html/TR/TR2/TR2-2.html\n'], '"19"': ['172.16.255.112', '/var/www/html/TR/TR1/TR1-2.html\n'], '"8"': ['172.16.255.104', '/var/www/html/MC/MC-4.html\n'], '"36"': ['172.16.255.151', '/var/www/html/TR/TR5/TR5-1.html\n'], '"18"': ['172.16.255.111', '/var/www/html/TR/TR1/TR1-1.html\n'], '"13"': ['172.16.255.2', '/var/www/html/MDF/MDF-2.html\n'], '"5"': ['172.16.255.101', '/var/www/html/MC/MC-1.html\n'], '"31"': ['172.16.255.141', '/var/www/html/TR/TR4/TR4-1.html\n'], '"42"': ['172.16.255.172', '/var/www/html/TR/TRTC/TRTC-2.html\n']}
```

Comment: "It is my understanding that my code..."?  You wrote it, but aren't sure what it does?

Comment: You're creating a csv reader `reader = csv.reader(infile)` but then not using it and instead looping over the 'raw' lines in the file. Is that intentional?

Comment: Your dictionary `d` output looks (sort of) ok, based on what you're asking. The keys have some extra double quotes in them, but that will be easy to fix. The values are 2-item lists, with the IP as the first list item, and the filename as the second list item (with a trailing newline, but again that will be easy to fix. So... what is the exact problem with what you've got so far? What are you unable to do/understand?

Comment: Scott -- I think I am aware of what my code is doing so far.  Essentially, just reading the "Reference File" into a dictionary. (Key, Value) pairs.

Comment: Tom -- 1.) I do not know the difference between looping over the 'raw' lines and using the csv.reader function. I will look at some documentation  2.) Ok, The extra double quotes are coming from the sequential key... I will update that. I am new to programming, How can i remove the "\n" after each dictionary entry? Would not removing the trailing newline have negative effects later? I am curious and uneducated.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, what you want to do is you want to access the IPs sequentially and perform some action after that.

I can see the keys in your dictionaries have additional quotes. Try displaying d['4']. It will throw an error.
To remove this you should use Python's builtin csv reader module.

Something like this should work fine:

```
with open('coors.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    with open('coors_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
```

Now let's see how you can loop through the dict.

```
for key in d:
    serialNo = key
    correspondingIP = d[serialNo][0]
    correspondingFilename = d[serialNo][1]
```

This should help you to get rid of extra quotes :
[Remove quotes in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067572/remove-quotes-in-python-dictionary)

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: beginner007, This is essentially what I am looking for. This code will create 2 variables from the list within the dictionary called "correspondingIP" and "correspondingFilename"?  I can then use these variables in a telnet script to do what I am trying to accomplish! I will test this and let you know!

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Comment: I'm looking to improve my reputation on Stackoverflow. I could really use a +1 on my answer. Thanks :D

Comment: I voted up... but i still have too low of a reputation for my vote to count

Answer (score 0):

Thanks EVERYONE for taking the time to look at this for me!  Like I said I am a python newbie. I am also trying to get the basics of Software Defined Networking (SDN) I have learned alot from you all taking the time to post ideas and thoughts.

Here is my code now:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import csv

d = {}
with open('/var/www/html/Test_Output.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
  with open('/var/www/html/Directory.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in infile:
      rows = ( line.split(",") for line in infile )
      d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
#print(d)

for key in d:
  serialNo = key
  correspondingIP = d[serialNo][0]
  correspondingFilename = d[serialNo][1]
  print(serialNo, correspondingIP, correspondingFilename)
```

Now, I feel much better as I can reference each dictionary item (Key, IP Address, Filename) individually and easily. This code should be a solid base for grabbing the configurations off each device remotely.

Thanks Again!